# Volume Control for Audio source from VideoClp from VideoPlayer

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, video-player

I'm trying to setup a volume control slider for my video player but having a tough time trying to figure out how to control the volume in the video clip inside Unity Video Player.  I can't seem to link the audio source to the video clip so I can control the volume.  I don't have any problem with individual mp3 audio files but can't get it to work with video files.

Any suggestions?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class track : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{

    public AudioSource audio;
    public Slider audiovolume;

    public VideoPlayer video;
    Slider tracking;
    bool slide = false;

    void Start()
    {

        tracking = GetComponent<Slider>();

    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData a)
    {

        slide = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData a)
    {

        float frame = (float)tracking.value * (float)video.frameCount;
        video.frame = (long)frame;
        slide = false;

    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (!slide && video.isPlaying)

            tracking.value = (float)video.frame / (float)video.frameCount;
    }

    public void volume()
    {

        audio.volume = audiovolume.value;

    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem to link te audiovolume slider in any way.
Try this:

```
void Start()
{

    tracking = GetComponent<Slider>();
    if (audiovolume!=null && audio!=null) 
    audiovolume.onValueChanged.AddListener((x)=>audio.volume=x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks zambari, I have just added your code but it didn't seem to work.  The volume slider is attached to the track.volume, but right now, the audio source isn't attached.  Somehow, I can't seem to add the video player to the audio (audio source), only mp3.

Comment: If i can some how add the videoplayer to the audio (audio source), it should work.

Comment: I haven't actually had a chance to check it myself in full detail, but as you know there's a few modes of the videoPlayer's output, one of them uses audioSource but I heard you need to do it via code at a specific point, after the video is ready but before playback (I might be wrong here), otherwise the player might override the setting (I think it matterer url vs videoclip too)

Comment: Thanks either way.  Like I said before, if I drop a mp3 into the audio, it work fine.  But it won't allow me to add a video clip.  I just need to figure out how to attach the audioSource output to  the Videoplayer.